# Invoke method CsSCript Notepad++

Tags: visual-studio, notepad++, invoke-command, cs-script

I have this simple method CallMethod made in Notepad++ with CsScript.
How to invoke in from VS ?

```
namespace TestCall
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class ClassCall
    {
        public void CallMethod()
        {
            Console.Write("MethodCalling");
        }
    }
}
```

I made this invoker

```
namespace TestCall
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class Class1
    {
        public ClassCall a = new ClassCall();
        public void Invoker()
        {
            Console.Write("MethodCall");
            a.CallMethod();
            Console.Write("MethodCalled");
        }
    }
}
```

But how to call it to be opened with Notepad++ with CSScript, so i can debug it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CS-Script offers a debugging option which can be used when you create an script.
Here's the github [documentation](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script.npp#usage).

Put the cursor on the line you want a breakpoint and press F9.

[image]

Comment: Hi @javdromero, thanks for the anser, but i would like to know how to invoke the method from VS application.
How to call a method, and open it with Notepadd++ and return some value

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you can't connect VS with Notepad++.